# in a graph with minimum degree 1, get the expected value of the degree of a uniform random neighbor of a uniformly random vertex

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value

I came across this exercise in one of my old notes in class:

> Consider a simple undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ on $n$ vertices such that the minimum degree is 1. Let $x$ be a uniformly random vertex and $y$ be a uniformly random neighbor of $x$. Let $Z$ be the degree of $y$. Show that $$\mathbb{E}[Z] = \frac{1}{|V|} \sum_{ab \in E} \left(\frac{deg(a)}{deg(b)}+ \frac{deg(b)}{deg(a)} \right).$$

I'm not too sure how to get the given expression for $\mathbb{E}[Z]$, my gut feeling is that it is the sum (over all vertices) of the product of the probability of obtaining a vertex and the probability of obtaining the neighbors of the vertex and the degree of the neighbor. How do we get the expected value to be that sum (over the edges) of ratios of degrees of the incident vertices?

Answer (score 1):

For every edge $ab$, there is a $\frac1{|V|} \cdot \frac1{\deg a}$ probability of starting at $a$ and going to $b$, which results in $Z = \deg b$. There is also a $\frac1{|V|} \cdot \frac1{\deg b}$ probability of starting at $b$ and going to $a$, which results in $Z = \deg a$.